# Dependency inject IOrchardServices into aspx codebehind constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, orchardcms

The team and I are looking at Orchard to use as our CMS. We have a fairly large ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms app and we can only migrate the bits one piece at a time. With that in mind, we will still serve our aspx pages and slowly convert them into the CMS as time allows.

I've noticed on the docs @ orchardproject.net/docs, link [here](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/%28S%28t3jueyv1qpbxcw2a25lpsv45%29%29/Print.aspx?Page=Developer-FAQ), about how one does authorization inside a module. So all that has to be done is include IOrchardService in the constructor of a controller and it'll get injected at runtime.

```
public AdminController(IMyService myService, IOrchardServices orchardServices) {
    _myService = myService;
    Services = orchardServices;
}
```

Because the conversion process will be slow, ¿can I provide a constructor with the IOrchardServices on a System.Web.UI.Page subclass?

```
// something like this
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    IOrchardServices _service;

    public Test(IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    {
        _service = orchardServices;
    }
}
```

This does not work, throws an exception expecting a default constructor. If I place the default constructor, the page loads correctly but IOrchardServices is not injected. ¿Is this even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does everyone say dependency injection in ASP.NET webforms is hard when PageHandlerFactory and IHttpHandlerFactory exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504150/why-does-everyone-say-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-webforms-is-hard-when-pageh)

Comment: that other post does look similar, but my main question is whether I have to do something like what is mentioned in that previous post or if I have to tell Orchard that I want to inject aspx pages as well. From the orchard docs, looks like for their default stuff such as IOrchardServices all one has to do is place an IOrchardServices as a param in your constructor on your controller and are good to go. Cant seem to do that with the webforms with Orchard or am I incorrect in that.

Comment: This is cross-posted from http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/265781

Cross-posting does dilute our efforts to answer questions...

Comment: Did you ever solve this in the end? having the same problem