# Where can I define a constructor parameter for a page class

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, mvp

```
public partial class DataPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    IPersonPresenter presenter = null;

    public DataPage(IPersonPresenter presenter)
    {
        if (presenter == null) throw new Exception("Didn't receiver the presenter");

        this.presenter = presenter;
    }
}
```

I need to pass presenter as a Dependency Injection paramter for this ASP.Net web forms class. I tried Global.asax but couldn't find a factory or anything similar. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Last time I looked, ASP.NET Web Forms doesn't have an extensibility point that enable you to do this, but ASP.NET MVC does. For Web Forms, a possible approach is outlined in my book Dependency Injection in .NET, section 7.5 http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does everyone say dependency injection in ASP.NET webforms is hard when PageHandlerFactory and IHttpHandlerFactory exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504150/why-does-everyone-say-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-webforms-is-hard-when-page)

Comment: I was mainly trying to have an example of MVP pattern.
Could we do it in `Global.asax` file?