# Constructor injection not working in .NET 4.7.2 Dependency Injection in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I used article "Use Dependency Injection In WebForms Application" https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/use-dependency-injection-in-webforms-application/
The project retargeted to .NET Framework 4.7.2 in project properties and in web.config:

```
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.72" ...
```

AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity NuGet package is installed.
Type is registered in Global:

```
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var container = this.AddUnity();
            container.RegisterType<IVCRole, eVCRole>();
        }
        ...
```

I checked container and it is working and registering interface IVCRole mapping to class eVCRole.
Default.aspx.cs is refactored:

```
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    private IVCRole vcr; 
    public Default(IVCRole avcr) 
    { 
      vcr = avcr;
    }   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...
```

But when I run web application there is an error
"Constructor on type 'ASP.default_aspx' not found."
If I add this constructor:

```
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    private IVCRole vcr;
    public Default() {}
    public Default(IVCRole avcr)
    { 
      vcr = avcr;
    }   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...
```

the constructor for DI

```
    public Default(IVCRole avcr) 
    { 
      vcr = avcr;
    }
```

is never called and "vcr" is always null in Page_Load.
There is an article: "Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web Forms":
https://makingloops.com/dependency-injection-in-web-forms/
where this error is mentioned:
"On occasion you may see a build error complaining about the lack of a zero-argument constructor on the page. I notice that this error will magically go away depending on the context. Someone else suggested using property injection with the Dependency attribute on pages to get around this, but i didn’t find that was necessary."
But in my case there is no "magic".
There is similar question in Stackoverflow:
[.NET 4.7.2 Dependency Injection in ASP.NET WebForms Website - Constructor injection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177252/net-4-7-2-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-webforms-website-constructor-inject)
But in my case property injection is not working:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [Dependency]
    public IVCRole vcr { get; set; }    

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...
```

"vcr" in Page_Load is still null.
There is solution to get it working with custom implementation of DI provider but I already using .NET 4.7.2 an Unity. Author mentioned that for web application should not be any problem as the problem is with website compiler.
How to get DI constructor or property injection to working in Default page using .NET 4.7.2 and Unity?

This is Stack:

```
[MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'ASP.default_aspx' not found.]
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1173
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +130
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +21
   Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity.ContainerServiceProvider.DefaultCreateInstance(Type type) +17
   Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity.ContainerServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) +161
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_mmaneivx.Create_ASP_default_aspx() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\19e4d468\8c7800a0\App_Web_mmaneivx.2.cs:0
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +31
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +104
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +33
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) +39
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +386
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

Comment: What NuGet package are you using, exactly? The NuGet packages based on Unity are rather old, have you looked at packages that use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` instead, such as this one ( https://github.com/Jehoel/AspNetDependencyInjection )? (shameless plug: I wrote this one)

Comment: Is this a typo in the question or the config file? `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.72"`

Comment: @Dai, I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity 1.0.0 published June 4 2018.

Comment: @stuartd, yes it was type in my web.config but after fixing it to 4.7.2 it still not working.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I maintain [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jehoel.AspNetDependencyInjection/) [and project](https://github.com/Jehoel/AspNetDependencyInjection) that use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` for ASP.NET WebForms (and MVC, SignalR and WCF) in the .NET Framework 4.7.2 - however the content of this post isn't specific to my implementation of DI for ASP.NET.

---

- Check your `.csproj`:

  - Ensure you're targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later (note that many shared web-hosts - including Azure App Services - may be running older versions of the .NET Framework):

    ```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ```
- Check your `web.config`

  - Ensure you have `<system.web><compilation targetFramework="4.7.2">`
  - Ensure you have `<system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>`
  - If you have `<assemblies><clear />` ensure you have `<add assembly="*"/>` *after* the `<clear />` or otherwise ensure you're explicitly listing all required assemblies in `<add />` elements.
- Your `ConfigureServices` method (or anything that configures DI) **must run before `Global.asax`'s `Application_Start`!**

  - Currently your code is instantiating the Unity container as a local inside `Application_Start` - this is a bad idea (as you aren't preserving a strong-reference in a field - a bug elsewhere could cause the GC to collect your DI container, which would be a bad thing.
  - You also need to add a `IHttpModule` to support scoped DI containers (my package does this for you already).
  - This is done by using the `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute (from `WebActivatorEx`.

    - Note that `PreApplicationStartMethod` **is not the same** as OWIN's `[assembly: Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup()` attribute! Your project may need to use both if you're using DI with SignalR.
    - Your Startup class code should look like this:

    ```
    [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod ( typeof( global::MyProject.RssStartup ), methodName: nameof( global::MyProject.MyStartup.OnPreStart ) )]

    namespace MyProject
    {
        internal static class MyStartup
        {
            internal static void OnPreStart()
            {
                // Set-up your DI system here and then call your `ConfigureServices` method before this method returns.
            }
        }
    }
    ```

Comment: .csproj:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
web.config:
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.72".
There is no <assemblies><clear />.
I do not know what you are talking about "Your ConfigureServices method (or anything that configures DI)" - I do not have anything else what I put in my question. That is exactly how it instructed in my first link to Microsoft.
Where should I put "PreApplicationStartMethod"? What StartUp class do you mean? Is it Global or Page class?

Comment: about your disclaimer. I am in process of moving this web application to MVC Core. So your NuGet package and project may me related to extended form of this question.

Comment: Dai, Thanks for this. In my case adding `targetFramework` to `<httpRuntime>` fixed it. All the other criteria you listed were already in place. I can use ctor injection in WebForms now.

Comment: Thanks for the work on the NuGet packages @Dai!  I'm attempting to use the library on a WebForms "Web Site" but I'm having some trouble - it looks as if it may only work on a WebForms Web Application (pre-compiled).  I was hoping to utilize this as a means to ease the migration away from WebForms :-/

Comment: @SirCodesALot You will need to convert your _Website_ into a _Web Application_ first. There’s no way around that, sorry - fortunately it’s straightforward and VS (at least up-to VS2015, maybe VS2017?) has a migration wizard that generates a csproj for you and dispenses with App_Code.

Comment: @Dei It's interesting why that wouldn't work - but my bet would possibly be security  related.  IIRC, MS was encouraging to get away from Web Sites for the flexibility of MSBuild since then too.  I was giving it a good go though! Thanks again!

Comment: @SirCodesALot It won't work because Websites can't use NuGet packages...

Comment: I was able to install NuGet packages & get them to work with the WF WebSite.  No matter what I tried, I couldn't get the "resolver" to work to work - it may be related to the run-time compilation vs pre-compliation too.  In any case, I'm going to be converting them to WAPs

Comment: @SirCodesALot Forgive my ignorance, but _how on earth_ did you install a NuGet package into a project-without-a-csproj? (or did you manually extract the `.nupkg` file? or is there some magic in `nuget.exe install`?)

Comment: Opened up the NuGet package manager, searched and installed NuGet packages.  it created a packages.config file, added runtime assembly binding to Web.config & copied the files to the bin folder.  The downloaded packages are stored in a packages folder on the same level as the solution (.sln) file.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem (exception `MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'ASP.*my_page*_aspx' not found.`) and it turned out that there was error in creating inner dependency.

I mean, I had:

```
public class Global :  System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private IUnityContainer container;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        container = this.AddUnity();

        container.RegisterType<IDataStorage>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => DataStorageBuilder.GetDefaultStorage()));

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

and Page:

```
public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private IDataStorage storage { get; set; }

    public Contact(IDataStorage storage)
    {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        storage.DoRequest();
    }
}
```

And DataStorageBuilder.GetDefaultStorage() actually threw exception, which Unity wrapped in `Constructor on type 'ASP.contact_aspx' not found`.

So maybe, you need to check that container can correctly create all inner dependencies of page (in your example it is `eVCRole`).

Comment: Thank you! Turned on "Common Language Runtime" exceptions in Exception Settings and there it was:- a failure to create an inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to remove `optimizeCompilations="true"` from:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" optimizeCompilations="true">
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

in Web.Config

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue as the above answer by Света Нестерова https://stackoverflow.com/a/65205408/6901318

One of the dependencies I was trying to register was from an internally maintained Nuget package.

For whatever reason, it is not able to register the type when it is defined in a dll like that. I have done this with .Net Core and it works fine. I am assuming that those references have not been resolved at this point in the application startup. I could be wrong though. It is just a guess, if anyone knows please comment on it.

I ended up making an empty class that inherited from the class I wanted to inject. And, that also implemented the interface that was defined in the NuGet package.

```
public interface IADAuthenticationManager: IADManager
{

}
```

IADAuthenticationManager is the wrapper interface and IADManager is the interface defined in the package.

```
public class ADAuthenticationManager: ADManager, IADAuthenticationManager
{
    public ADAuthenticationManager(IADProvider aDProvider, IErrorLogger logger) : 
    base(aDProvider, logger)
    {
    }
}
```

ADAuthenticationManager is the wrapper class. ADManager is the class that implements IADManager and is also defined in the NuGet package. IADAuthenticationManager is the wrapper interface from above.

In my Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...            
        var container = this.AddUnity();
        ...
        container.RegisterType<IADManager, ADAuthenticationManager>();
        container.RegisterType<IADAuthenticationManager, ADAuthenticationManager>();
    }
```

The classes in the NuGet package also had some dependencies that needed wrapper classes created as well. It was a process. But, everything is working now.